# Add selected attribute to a option based on a expression in Aurelia

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2, aurelia

I have a **select** html tag(using select2) in my Aurelia view in which I want to add the `selected` attribute to a **option** tag based on an boolean expression. The expression will be true only once. Here is my code(this works fine):

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single" style="width:200px;">
  <option repeat.for="region of personRegionDetail" value="${region.Id}">${region.Name}</option>
</select>
```

I am looking for something like this(if it`s possible) inside my **option** tag:

```
${if(region.Id === persondetail.RegionId){ selected }}
```

I also tried using jQuery, but this shows me the selected option only when I refresh the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //Initialize select2
  $('select.js-example-basic-single').select2();
  //I tried this
  //The searched option value contains ${persondetail.RegionId} 
  $('select.js-example-basic-single').val("${persondetail.RegionId}").trigger("change");
</script>
```

I acces the page from another view by clicking to a link using `route-href="route:routename"`(if it tells something).

My question is how can I solve this problem to show the selected option when I entered to the page?

**EDIT:**
I need to initialize the select2 after some miliseconds in order to shows the selected option(probably I must wait for the API to respond). This caused the problem with jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `selected.bind`:

```
<option repeat.for="region of personRegionDetail" value="${region.Id}" selected.bind="region.Id === $parent.Id">${region.Name}</option>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Uy6eQWZu6PrOwaXeArOx?p=preview

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need!

Comment: I need to initialize the select2 after some miliseconds(30ms) in order to work correctly. Probably I need to wait to the API to send the data...

Comment: if you put your code in a plnkr, I can help you... You should probably initialize only after the callback, probably using a promise or smg like that.

Comment: Based on your advice I tried to initialize it in the promise(after I got the data), but seems doesn`t solve the problem. Without select2(using only a simple select) it works perfectly, so your concept is good. I will write to the Aurelia team about that. Thank you for helping!

Comment: note that since selected is a one way binding, selected.bind will instantiate a one way binding